# A question about isomorphic between two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

[image]

For groups $G_1,G_2$ define $f:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ by $f(x)=e^x$. This bijection is an isomorphism hence (3) is correct

can any one explain  for remaining i am so thank full advance

Comment: 1 is false since the domain is countable but the codomain is not.

Comment: Broad hints: (1) can't possibly be true because of size, but you can also find specific conditions satisfied by the RHS that aren't satisfied by the left for both (1) and (2); in particular, what does $(-1)^2=1$ tell you?  For (4), on the LHS you always have a 'half' of any element; $\forall y\exists x$ s.t. $x+x=y$. Is this true on the RHS?

Comment: Note that all of these rely on the fundamental principle that isomorphic groups have the same _theory_ - that is, the set of sentences true in one group is exactly the set of sentences true in the other. So to prove non-isomorphism, all you have to do is find a sentence that's true in one group but not the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. False. Look at the cardinality.
2. Suppose true and $f(x)=-1$. Then $f(x/2+x/2)=f(x/2)^2=-1$ which is impossible
3. Take $\exp$ I assume real numbers >0
4. Suppose true and $f(x)=2$. Then $f(x/2+x/2)=f(x/2)^2=2$ which is impossibe in $\mathbb{Q}$.